# Setting Environment Variables for VSCode Debug session

Tags: visual-studio-code

I must be missing something very obvious here, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I want to set an environment variable `FOO` to be available in the VSCode debug sessions started on the current file by hitting the Debug button in the top right corner

This one:  [image].

I tried setting the `env` dictionary in the `launch.json` file like so:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {
                "FOO": "BAR"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to read the variable in my code, is get a `KeyError` since the variable hasn't been set.

```py
import os
print(os.environ["FOO"])
```

yields this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../save_model.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(os.environ["FOO"])
  File ".../lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'FOO'
```

Comment: what if you use `F5` with that launch config, use the Run button in the Debug Bar, in all the years I use VSC I have never used the top-right button

Comment: how curious -- F5 works indeed. Thanks a bunch -- I will file an issue on the VSCode github.

Comment: I have never seen documentation of that top-right button, I have no clue what it does and which extension does create it

Comment: I just spent around three hours trying to figure out this problem. WTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that if you hit `F5`, everything works as expected. If, however you use the button shown above, environment variables are not set per the `launch.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for revealing this insanity! or perhaps there is logical explanation? I'm just too dumb to see it!